# Why tun/tap multiqueue can not balance between each queue?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tap, tun

refer: [tuntap](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt)

I have create multithread for each tun/tap queue. And each thread use their own libev loop. And when use `ping` to create low-speed flow, every queue will be awakened. But when use `iperf3` create high-speed flow, all packet will be distributed to one thread.

below is the `ping` log, thread `140213476759296` and `140213468366592` will receive packet cross.

```
(140213476759296) tapsw.c +171 tap_recv_cb()
(140213468366592) tapsw.c +171 tap_recv_cb()
(140213476759296) tapsw.c +171 tap_recv_cb()
(140213468366592) tapsw.c +171 tap_recv_cb()
```

But with `iperf3`:

```
(140213468366592) tapsw.c +171 tap_recv_cb()
(140213468366592) tapsw.c +171 tap_recv_cb()
(140213468366592) tapsw.c +171 tap_recv_cb()
(140213468366592) tapsw.c +171 tap_recv_cb()
```

Why tun/tap multiqueue can not balance between each queue?

Answer (score 0):

kernel tun will use four tuple hash key to identify one flow. So iperf3 will be only in one queue.